# frequency analysis with unevenly spaced data in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have a signal generated by a simulation program.  Because the solver in this program has a variable time step, I have a signal with unevenly spaced data.  I have two lists, a list with the signal values, and another list with the times at which each value occurred.  The data could be something like this

```
npts = 500
t=logspace(0,1,npts)
f1 = 0.5 
f2 = 0.6
sig=(1+sin(2*pi*f1*t))+(1+sin(2*pi*f2*t))
```

I would like to be able to perform a frequency analysis on this signal using python.  It seems I cannot use the fft function in numpy, because this requires evenly spaced data.  Are there any standard functions which could help me find the frequencies contained in this signal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common algorithm to solve such things is called a [Least-Squares Spectral analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis) of frequencies. It looks like this will be in a future release of the [scipy.signals package](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/signal.html?highlight=lomb#least-squares-spectral-analysis-spectral). Maybe there is a current version, but I can't seem to find it... In addition, there is some code available from [Astropython](http://www.astropython.org/blog/2010/9/Question-period-finding-packages-in-python), which I will not copy in it's entirety, but it essentially creates a lomb class which you can use the following code to get some values out.. What you need to do is the following:

```
import numpy
import lomb
x = numpy.arange(10)
y = numpy.sin(x)
fx,fy, nout, jmax, prob = lomb.fasper(x,y, 6., 6.)
```

Comment: There do seem to be a couple of indenting problems in the lomb class, but otherwise it works just as I'd hoped!

Comment: Link to gist with fixed indentation: https://gist.github.com/louismullie/1cb1cae74ef76513827a

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, just look up the formula for a Fourier transform, and implement it as a discrete sum over your data values:

given a set of values `f(x)` over some set of `x`, then for each frequency `k`,

```
F(k) = sum_x ( exp( +/-i * k *x ) )
```

choose your `k`'s  ranging from `0` to `2*pi / min separation in x`.

and, you can use `2 * pi / max(x)` as the increment size

For a test case, use something for which you known the correct answer, c.f., a single `cos( k' * x )` for some `k'`, or a Gaussian.

Comment: Please consider answering with an example output, as it will help a lot of users how will find this question.

Comment: This is just a schematic of the function.  The F(k) will be complex values at whatever set of k's that you choose.

Comment: One more comment,  this method treats the input set of independent variables as a set of delta functions, much the same as implied in a FFT.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way out is to interpolate to evenly-spaced time intervals